# TextInput entered data is not visible using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<TextInput value="test" palceholder="Enter text"></TextInput>
```

Here in this TextInput component if i remove the "value" attribute then user entered data is visible properly .But i can't remove this "value" attribute bacause while retrieve the data i am using this "value" attribute to place the saved value

Answer (score 1):

`TextInput` is a controlled component, which means that if you want to set its value, you need to then manage its value yourself.

At its simplest, you can listen to the `onChangeText` event to be notified when user types into the input, and store the current value in the component state:

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={currentValue => this.setState({currentValue})}
  value={this.state.currentValue}
  />
```

The latest value is then always available as `this.state.currentValue`, and you can update the value by `this.setState({currentValue: yourSavedValue})`.